# Expressing trig equations in different form

Tags: trigonometry

Express $\sqrt{5}\cos(x)+2\sin(x)$ in the form $R\cos(x - \alpha)$ where $R > 0$ and $0° < \alpha < 90°$, giving the value of $\alpha$ correct to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the well-known fact that $$\cos(x-a) = \cos(x)\cos(a)+\sin(x)\sin(a)$$

For $R \cos(x-a) = \sqrt{5}\cos(x)+2\sin(x)$, this gives: $\sqrt{5} = R \cos(a)$ and $2 = R\sin(a)$. Divide one by the other and $\tan(a) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Since for the second part you also need $R$: Just square both equations and add, you get $R^2\cos^2(a) + R^2\sin^2(a) = 5 + 4 = 9\, \Rightarrow\,R^2=9\,\Rightarrow\, R=3$.

Comment: The following questions says this:

Hence solve the equation $$ \sqrt {5} cos\frac {1}{2} x + 2sin\frac {1}{2} x = 1.2 $$

for $0° < x < 360°$

Comment: How do I go this kind of question? Do I just plug in $\frac {1}{2} x$ into $Rcos(x - \alpha)$ where $x$ is?

Comment: Yes, pretty much: From what we derived in the first part you know that $\sqrt{5}\cos(x/2) + 2\sin(x/2) = 3\cos(x/2-\alpha)$. Therefore, to solve for $x$, all you need is to solve $3\cos(x/2-\alpha) = 1.2$, i.e., $x = 2(\cos^{-1}(0.4)+\alpha)$.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Comment: Wait, how do you get from $3cos(\frac {x}{2} - \alpha ) = 1.2$ to $x = 2(cos^{-1}(0.4) + \alpha)$?

Comment: $3\cos(x/2-\alpha) = 1.2 \; \Rightarrow \cos(x/2-\alpha) = 0.4 \; \Rightarrow x/2-\alpha = \cos^{-1}(0.4)\; \Rightarrow x/2 = \cos^{-1}(0.4) +\alpha ; \Rightarrow x = 2(\cos^{-1}(0.4) +\alpha)$

Comment: Oh ok!! Thank you very much, I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

We first start by assuming that $\root \of 5 = R\cos \alpha$ and $2 = R \sin \alpha$. Then we have that $$R\cos \alpha  \cos x + R \sin \alpha  \sin x$$ Which resembles if you can recall the additive cosine rule $\cos(A \pm B) = \cos A \cos B \mp \sin A \cos B $ so we end up with

$$R\cos (x- \alpha)$$

Now to solve for $R$ and $\alpha$. First note that $ \frac{\root \of 5}{2}= \frac{R \sin \alpha}{R\cos \alpha} = \tan \alpha$ and also note $5 + 4 = R^2\cos^2 \alpha + R^2 \sin \alpha \implies R^2 = 9 $. You can finish off

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$R=\sqrt {(\sqrt{5})^2+2^2}=3$$
thus

$$\sqrt {5}\cos(x)+2\sin(x)=$$

$$3 (\frac{\sqrt {5}}{3}\cos (x)+\frac {2}{3}\sin (x))= $$

$$3\cos (x-\alpha) $$
with
$$\cos (\alpha )=\frac {\sqrt {5}}{3} $$
and
$$\sin (\alpha)=\frac {2}{3} $$

from here,  you get $\alpha\approx 41^\circ.81 $.